# How align in math mode multi rows without take in account some rows

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment

If we want align only equation lines:

```
          1. y=x+z        
          2. y=a+b
          3. y=t+g
```

We do by add '&':

```
\begin{align*}
    &1. y=x+z\\ 
    &2. y=a+b\\
    &3. y=t+g
\end{align*}
```

But if we need to get-these lines aligned in math mode with text line that we don't want to take in account:

```
          1. y=x+z
    word1 word2 word3 word4
          2. y=a+b
          3. y=t+g
```

How can we do above output?
I use below hack that solve the problem partly(not really center)-'&' in the center of word line between \text tags.

```
 \begin{align*}
    &1. y=x+z\\
    \text{word1 word2} & \text{word3 word4}\\
    &2. y=a+b\\
    &3. y=t+g
\end{align*}
```

How above problem can be resolved in standard way without hack above?

In other words how can be text line excluded for '&' calculation and done only by equation lines

(or how align in math mode multi rows according equation position without take in account the text line).

Thanks

Comment: by `\intertext{word1 word2 word3 word4}` (without of ` \\ ` on the end). Text will be aligned to left text border.-

Comment: @Zarko is right. But @Ben what if you use a different structure as `\begin{enumerate}`? As far as I can tell you need to put three equations one below the other with an enumeration at the beginning. Am I right?

Comment: @LukeTheWolf, this is not entirely clear. OP may look for equation numbering on the left side (by use `amsmath` package and option `leqno`), or just locally for this set of equations by use of `nccmath` package and environment `{fleqn}[<distance from left margin> ]`.

Comment: none of these examples are using `align` as intended, your 1.  ... 3. should be marked as equation numbers not as part of the equation, the normal place to put the `&`  would be before the =   so `&=`

Comment: @Zarko your answer works! Thanks! If we want also to center then \intertext{\centering word1 word2 word3 word4}